# Attempt to elevate to chroot capabilities but fails, WHY?

Tags: go, chroot, linux-capabilities

In order to execute

```
must(syscall.Chroot("/home/nora/Bureau/Perso/os/ubuntu-base-14.04-core-amd64"))
```

I need to grant SYS_CHROOT capability to the process as follows :

```
    // Temporarily add SYS_CHROOT capability
    if err := c.SetFlag(cap.Effective, true, cap.SYS_CHROOT); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to set capability: %v", err)
    }

    // Re-check the capabilities (SYS_CHROOT should now be effective)
    c = cap.GetProc()
    log.Printf("this process has these caps: %s", c)

    // Check if the capability is granted
    if on, _ := c.GetFlag(cap.Permitted, cap.SYS_CHROOT); !on {
        log.Fatalf("Insufficient privilege to execute syscall.Chroot - required capability not granted")
    }

    // Execute the syscall.Chroot operation
    must(syscall.Chroot("/home/nora/Bureau/Perso/os/ubuntu-base-14.04-core-amd64"))

    // Remove SYS_CHROOT capability
    if err := c.SetFlag(cap.Effective, false, cap.SYS_CHROOT); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to remove capability: %v", err)
    }
```

But I get exit:status 1 Insufficient privilege to execute syscall.Chroot - required capability not granted, which means the process hasn't been granted chroot capabilities. Any clue on what could be the problem ?

Comment: Maybe check the "permitted" capabilities first? Maybe the process doesn't have the authority to escalate its chroot permissions?  Yeah, just guessing. (aside: 'chroot' is fun, I used it about 34 years ago on SysV to sandbox an app).

Comment: You need another call to apply the effective capability. I've provided more detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The `c.SetFlag(...)` call only raises the effective bit in the `c` capability `Set`. You also need to apply that `cap.Set` to the process with [`c.SetProc()`](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap#Set.SetProc):

```golang
if err := c.SetProc(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to apply capabilities, %q: %v", c, err)
}
```